# ¿Cómo hacer este filtro en Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

quiero filtrar en access solo los partos que llevan menor o igual a 3 meses `int(datediff("m",format(cdate(fecha_parto),'dd/mm/yyyy'),now()) )<5`

```
SELECT 

format(cdate(fecha_parto),'dd/MM/yyyy') as FechaParto,
datediff("m",format(cdate(fecha_parto),'dd/MM/yyyy'),now()) as Cat_Mes

 FROM padron_general
where fecha_parto<>"" AND INT(datediff("m",format(cdate(fecha_parto),'dd/MM/yyyy'),now()) )<5
```

Comment: ¿cuál es el problema o error que tienes con la manera en la que ya lo haces? Por otro lado, dices en texto menor o igual a 3 meses, pero el código tiene ```< 5``` y debiera ser ```<= 3```

Comment: Amigo, Gracias de todas maneras ya solucione el error, despues muchas horas jajj.

Comment: Si lo resolviste, publica la solución como una respuesta, pues sería justo aportar dicha solución a la comunidad de la que esperas ayuda, o bien elimina la pregunta. Un saludo.